# Storing Files ( images, Microsoft office documents )

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

What is the best way for storing images and Microsoft Office documents:

- Google Drive
- Google Storage

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider checking this [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) to help you choose which storage option suits you best and also learn more.

To differentiate the two:

- [**Google Drive**](https://developers.google.com/drive/)

  A collaborative space for storing, sharing, and editing files, including Google Docs and is good for the following:

  - End-user interaction with docs and files
  - Collaborative creation and editing
  - Syncing files between cloud and local devices
- [**Google Cloud Storage**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/)

  A scalable, fully-managed, highly reliable, and cost-efficient object / blob store and good for these:

  - Images, pictures, and videos
  - Objects and blobs
  - Unstructured data

In addition to that, see [Google Cloud Platform - FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/faq#cloud_storage_vs_drive) for more insights.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches can be taken into consideration, *[google docs](https://www.google.com/docs/)* are widely used for online working with office documents etc, it provides probably same layout in comparison to Microsoft office, the advantage is that you can share the document with other people as well, plus you can edit it online at any time.

*[Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/)* (useful way to store your files)
Every Google Account starts with 15 GB of free storage that's shared across Google Drive, Gmail, and Google Photos. When you upgrade to Google One, your total storage increases to 100 GB or more depending on what plan you choose.

[*Mediafire*](https://www.mediafire.com/) (another useful way to store your files)
In mediafire on the basic package it allows you 10 GB of cloud space for free, the files you store in the MediaFire can be encrypted by password encryption. It allows more other features as well. A suggestion to explore.